# Open password file using python?

Tags: python

I have a file in which i have set up my credentials; i have named it creds.py. The content looks something like this :-

```
{ "username": "abc",

  "password": "xyz" }
```

i am trying to import this in my main.py file

```
import json
import sys
import urllib.request
import urllib.response
import creds

def main():
    credentials = creds
    with open('credentials') as f:
        credentials = json.load(f)
```

But i keep getting this error message :-

```
 with open('credentials') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials'
```

Can someone please point out what i am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Almost certainly the program is running from a different directory than the one the file is in. Use `os.getcwd()` (with import os) to figure out where your program thinks it is.

Comment: @NathanielFord i get `/home/user/my-directory`. This is where all the files are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. The file named `credentials` does not exist because you named the file `creds.py`. You need to change the line to:

```
with open('creds.py') as f:
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked!!! I'll accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You created a *module* called `creds` by creating a file called `creds.py`. This module can contain variables, so in `creds.py`, instead of simply dumping the dictionary, assign it to a name.

**creds.py**

```
credentials = {"username": "me@my.email.org", "password": "13eun4c9t4"}
```

Then when you `import creds`, the import manager makes your dictionary accessible as `creds.credentials`

**main.py**

```
import creds

print(f"Username: {creds.credentials['username']}")
print(f"Password: {creds.credentials['password']}")
```

gives the output:

```
Username: me@my.email.org
Password: 13eun4c9t4
```

This way, you don't have to read json files and you can create more variables and functions in the same module that are related to credentials.